# unable to save print document to xps

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm saving my printed document as XPS in the application start up path using the code below:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd = PreparePrintDocument();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = Application.StartupPath+"\\backup.xps";
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
pd.Print();
pd.Dispose();
```

This works fine in some PC's but in some others the following error occurs:

> "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt."

When i set the default printer to XPS the code works in all systems but when I change it to network printer the error occurs again.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to save your XPS file? I think the problem maybe there...

Comment: that i have added in the question

Comment: and the above code works fine in some systems.but in some only the error occurs

Comment: @Isma  the anwer you provided worked with a little modification.thank you

Comment: in your answer i added this line   pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName ="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" along with setting Printer name as XPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a "using" block instead of disposing the document yourself:

```
using(PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument()) 
{
    pd = PreparePrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = 
    Application.StartupPath+"\\backup.xps";
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "XPS";
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName ="Microsoft XPS Document Writer"        
    pd.Print();
}
```